# Why is this crontab not executing the shellscript?

Tags: cron

I think everybody is already sick of all those crontab-questions but I don't get my shell-script to work. I have googled and experimented hours, but I didn't find the answer. Here's my crontab:

```
@reboot /home/pi/test/test.sh
```

Please forgive me this easy question, but I don't find the right way. Some Information:

- The Shell-Script works when I execute in shell
- Yes, I made it executable by `sudo chmod +x test.sh`

Thanks a lot.

Comment: How do you know that's not executing?

Comment: The Shell-Script starts a Python-Script, which should let at least one LED light. And no LED is lighting after boot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has now worked after another hours of experimenting. This is the now working code:

```
@reboot sleep 10; sudo sh /home/pi/test/test.sh &
```